# How can I get all words from each line of an external .txt file

Tags: java

Following code gives me only the first word of each line. But there are multiple words in several lines. I think, that there is be a problem in while condition.

```
public void nacti() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    if(!jeNacten){
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("analyza.txt"));
        String slovo;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer;
        while((slovo = reader.readLine()) != null){
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(slovo, " //.//,");
            slovo = tokenizer.nextToken();
            seznamSlov.add(new Slovo(slovo));
        }
        reader.close();
        jeNacten=true;            
    }
}
```

After `slovo = reader.readLine()`, how can I get all words from String `slovo`?

Comment: The problem is that you don't seems to understand what the current while loop is doing. Once you will understand how your BuffeerReader is reading a line. You will understand what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through all tokens.

```
    while((slovo = reader.readLine()) != null){
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(slovo, " //.//,");
        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            slovo = tokenizer.nextToken();
            seznamSlov.add(new Slovo(slovo));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have a loop that iterates through lines of input. With this approach, you need to add an inner that will loop through words on one line.